# Pesquisar nome de usuário em uma Query do mongoose-paginate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Eu estou tentando fazer um campo de pesquisa de usuários e, para isso, vou receber via query param uma variável `search`, que irá conter a **string** de pesquisa (neste caso, o nome (ou parte de um nome) de um ou mais usuários).

Se eu estivesse fazendo essa query com um banco **SQL** numa linguagem como o **Java**, seria algo como:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE name LIKE '%" + search + "'";
```

Depois coloca essa variável `sql` dentro de um `preparedStatement` e executa a query.

Porém, estudando o mongoose-paginate, no NodeJS, eu não estou conseguindo fazer uma query desse tipo, pois não consigo pegar a variável que estou recebendo na URL e passá-la para a consulta do mongoose. Meu método `findByName` está assim:

```
async findByName(req, res){
    let { search, page=1, limit=10 } = req.query;
    page = parseInt(page);
    limit = parseInt(limit);

    const users = await User.paginate({ name: /^L/ }, {page, limit});

    return res.json(users);
}
```

Da maneira como está o código acima, todos os usuários que possuem o nome começando com "L" serão retornados. Mas eu quero substituir o trecho `const users = await User.paginate({ name: /^L/ }, {page, limit});` **por algo como** `const users = await User.paginate({ name: /^search/ }, {page, limit});`, ou seja, **passar a variável `search`**, que está vindo na URL, como parâmetro para a busca no banco de dados.

Já tentei fazer algo do tipo:

```
async findByName(req, res){
    let { search, page=1, limit=10 } = req.query;
    page = parseInt(page);
    limit = parseInt(limit);

    const consulta = "/^"+search+"/";

    const users = await User.paginate({ name: consulta }, {page, limit});

    return res.json(users);
}
```

Também tentei substituir por `User.paginate({ name: /^${search}/}, {page, limit});`, ou usar o operador 
" **`** " do JavaScript, para acessar a variável com a notação `${search}`, mas não obtive sucesso.

Alguém tem ideia de como isso deve ser feito? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode instanciar um objeto da classe RegExp pra conseguir concatenar strings dentro dele. Algo como: `const searchRegex = new RegExp('^' + search)`. Depois é só usar a constante `searchRegex` da mesma maneira que usou a regex literal no seu exemplo.

Comment: Funcionoou! Muito obrigado :D

Answer (score -2):

Sua função pode ser feita assim

```
async findByName(req, res){
    let { search, page=1, limit=10 } = req.query;
    page = parseInt(page);
    limit = parseInt(limit);

    const users = await User.paginate({ name: RegExp('^' + search) }, {page, limit});

    return res.json(users);
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).